# Redirect in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, redirect

Using Wordpress.. I would like to redirect to a certain page on the site if the user visits an archive is_archive()

How would I go about this please? Could I add something to functions.php?

Cheers,
Steve

Comment: if you have found answers you should accept them. 20% doesn't look very good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using WordPress hook in `functions.php`, just paste this snippet in your `functions.php`

```
function redirect_to_url(){
    if(is_archive()){
        $url='your redirect url url';
        wp_redirect( $url );
    }  

}
add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_to_url');
```

There is an article [**here**](http://heera.it/redirect-single-post-page), it may help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    wp_redirect($location);
    exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`wp_redirect` is just fine

```
if(is_archive()){
    wp_redirect($location);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your archive.php template file put an if statement at the top with header location redirect if the criteria for redirection is met, perhaps using is_page();  by the sounds of it

or if it is a certain page you could do something in .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin available to achieve this, please find it [here](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/)